# How to access cocos2d-x sprites in current scene from JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I want to access the children of a cocos2d-x scene from the Android JNI.

The scene is created in the **AppDelegate** as follows:

```
Director::getInstance()->runWithScene(MainScene::create());
//scene node has several children
```

The scene contains several sprites as children that should be manipulated in the JNI. In the scene initiation, sprites are added as follows:

```
Scene* MainScene::createScene() {
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = MainScene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool MainScene::init() {
    ...
    this->addChild(sprite, 7);
    ...
}
```

But when I want to access the sprite in the **JNI**, the scene does not contain any children. I tried  to access the children by tagname and also count the children as follows.

```
//INITIALIZE COCOS2D
void cocos_android_app_init (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
}

//ACCESS SPRITES IN SCENE
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_appname_AppActivity_manipulateSprite
    ( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){
    //MANIPULATE SCENE IN GL THREAD:
    Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread([&](){
        //ACCESS CHILDREN BY TAG
        auto child = Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildByTag(7);
        auto sprite = dynamic_cast<cocos2d::Sprite*>(child);
        //this sprite is NULL, but I set the sprite with 
        //tag "7" when the scene is created

        //COUNT THE CHILDREN
        int child_count = Director::getInstance()
            ->getRunningScene()->getChildrenCount(); 
        //why is the number of children zero?
    }
}
```

Please also **note** that when appending new childs to the scene from JNI, these newly created childs can be accessed, but not the ones created during initialization.

Also I tried to give the scene layer a tagname in the createScene method, but getRunningScene seems to have no children.

How can I access the children of the current scene from JNI correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call replaceScene and re-initiate the scene when first calling your JNI method.